# ¿Cómo bajar ultima información con git y gerrit?

Tags: git

Alguien conoce de algún material de estas herramientas, en español seria genial.

Por otro lado, estoy trabajando con estas herramientas, sin embargo no logro bajar la Info del Jefe de Área, que hizo un merge dese su PC al branch dev remoto.

He probado con:

Grabo el último trabajo:

```
$git stash
```

Bajo la información con:

```
$git fetch
```

Me ubico en el commit a donde quiero bajar la ultima versión:

```
$git review -d [numero-ticket-en-gerrit]
```

Traslado lo bajado con fetch a mi branch local:

```
$git rebase --onto origin/dev HEAD^ [branche-local]
```

Y no, no veo nada que se haya bajado o actualizado...

¿Alguien que me de un Tip?, a lo mejor se me paso por alto algo, o es otro proceso.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: el comando `git fetch` solo actualiza la cantidad de cambios pendientes de bajar en las ramas es solo informativo para saber que ramas tienen cambios, para actualizar tu rama con el código remoto debes hacer `git pull`

Comment: perfecto, gracias Roberto!